# Get first match of image name in URL (regex, Ruby)

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm trying to regex the first match of an image name in a URL (ruby).

Here's my current code:

```
@wikimedia_link.match(/(\/|:)([a-zA-Z\_\-0-9]*\.(jpeg|jpg|png|gif))/).try(:[], 2)
```

It works (returns "Samuel_L_Jackson_Comic_Con.jpg") if I have one match, i.e.

```
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Samuel_L_Jackson_Comic_Con.jpg
```

However, this returns an error (nil), and seems to be because there is "Lucy_desi_1957.JPG" and "220px-Lucy_desi_1957.JPG" in the url.

```
http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a5/Lucy_desi_1957.JPG/220px-Lucy_desi_1957.JPG
```

Any idea on how to just ge the first match?

Thank you!

Comment: http://QuentinUK.github.com/regex.html

Comment: Tried getting all matches and just using the first?

Comment: I changed the tag on your question; it has nothing to do with Ruby on Rails, only Ruby.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The following regex works for both of your examples

```
/^.+\/[\w:]+\.(jpe?g|png|gif)/i
```

And you can get just `"http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a5/Lucy_desi_1957.JPG"` with the following

```
"http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a5/Lucy_desi_1957.JPG/220px-Lucy_desi_1957.JPG".match(/^.+\/[\w:]+\.(jpe?g|png|gif)/i).to_a.first
```

If you're just after the filename itself, drop the `^.+\/` from the regex, leave it as simply

```
/[\w:]+\.(jpe?g|png|gif)/i
```

Using this version in the `match` will return only `"Lucy_desi_1957.JPG"`

In either case, if no match is found, `nil` will return.

Comment: I think he wants the file name at the end of the path.

Comment: Thanks, added `^.+\/` to the front end.

Comment: This doesn't get just the filename, it returns the entire url.

Comment: My regex originally was `/[\w:]+\.(jpe?g|png|gif)/i` *(check the edit history)*, but as @QuentinUK suggested, it looked like OP may have been wanting the URL in front too. Regardless, it looks like OP sorted things out. I've updated my answer to reflect my original pattern.

Comment: I realize that. I'm not sure where @QuentinUK got that idea, though; it seems to be the opposite of what the OP wanted :) Also, it appears (based on the first example output) that the OP only wants the original image filename, without the "File:" that gets added at the beginning by mediawiki in some urls related to an image.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the filename at the end add a $ to match the end.

```
/(/|:)([\w-\.]+\.(jpeg|jpg|png|gif)$)/i
```

Answer (score 0):

what you want is:

```
@wikimedia_link[/[^\/:]+\.(?i:jpeg|jpg|png|gif)/]
```

using the `(?i:...)` grouping switches to case insensitive matching, so either jpg or JPG will be matched.

Comment: Hmm. Not sure why this got voted down, since it is currently the only answer that actually returns the result asked for by the poster: the first occurrence of an image-like filename in a given URL. Oh well.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I'd do it:

```
2.0.0-p247 :008 > image_url = 'http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a5/Lucy_desi_1957.JPG/220px-Lucy_desi_1957.JPG'
 => "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a5/Lucy_desi_1957.JPG/220px-Lucy_desi_1957.JPG" 
2.0.0-p247 :009 > image_name = image_url.match( /[-_\w:]+\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/i ) => #<MatchData "220px-Lucy_desi_1957.JPG" 1:"JPG"> 
2.0.0-p247 :012 > image_name.to_s
 => "220px-Lucy_desi_1957.JPG"
```

Without IRB:

```
image_url = 'http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a5/Lucy_desi_1957.JPG/220px-Lucy_desi_1957.JPG'
image_name = image_url.match( /[-_\w:]+\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/i );
puts image_name #=> "220px-Lucy_desi_1957.JPG"
```

This solution is the best because it derives the file name of the image, be it from a simple url and a simple filename:

```
http://www.anexample.com/dog.jpg
```

or with a more complex filename:

```
http://www.anexample.com/342432_large-xs_dog.jpg
```

or if an image is referenced more than once in the URL:

```
http://www.anexample.com/cat.jpg/upload/342432_large-xs_dog.jpg/xs/342432_large-xs_dog.jpg
```